# Error: Invalid file path while importing all tables from MariaDB to Hive Database using Sqoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

Here is my import command using sqoop:

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://10.11.11.15:6306/siki_asmet?serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta --username micronics -P --hive-import --warehouse-dir /warehouse/siki --hive-database siki_ods --exclude-tables "Sheet1$" --m 1;
```

When i run the above command, i get the following error:

```
SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path ''hdfs://master.lpjk.com:8020/warehouse/siki/_asdamkindo_personal_ska_pendidikan'':
No files matching path 
hdfs://master.lpjk.com:8020/warehouse/siki/_asdamkindo_personal_ska_pendidikan (state=42000,code=40000)
```

But when i run the same sqoop command again, it says the file already exists.

Comment: can  you please remove the `--warehouse-dir` parameter and try?

Comment: i did but no luck. same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. In my case one of the talbes' name was starting with a character underscore "_" because of which there was an issue where 2 single quotes were added automatically in the path of the hdfs directory where the copy of the file was stored.

I changed the name of the column by removing the underscore character and now i can import the table into Hive database. I think special characters like that are not easily parsed in Hive or HDFS.